# Call ObjC function from nodejs-mobile script

Tags: ios, node.js, objective-c

I am running a Websocket client using nodejs-mobile in my iOS app. The other part of my app is done in Objective C. I want to pass text messages received from the Websocket (nodejs-mobile layer) to the ObjC layer. I could not find a solution for it. Is it even possible and can someone provide a way to do this?

For example on JavaScript side something like:

```
callObjCfunction(myObjCfunction, textmessage);
```

On ObjC side something like:

```
- (void) myObjCfunction:(NSString*)textmessage { 
   [textfield setStringValue: textmessage];
}
```

Note: this is only an example. If there are other ways to communicate between these two layers I am interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which is surely not "best practice" and very limited but it works for me since I only want to pass text messages.

I'm calling `console.log()` in JavaScript and redirect the stdout in native ObjC.